# DISPhelper Library

Tags: com

Has anyone used DISPhelper library? I wanna know if it's really a better way to use this library if you're pretty new to COM technology. I'd appreciate your feedbacks. thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really better for a beginner. It's easy to use and comes along with a bunch of examples. But if you're into serious COM programming, better learn it the conventional way.